# POSTGRESQL - Insert into foreign table triggered insertion into another remote table

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have a problem to update records into my foreign table.

It refers to a remote table which have a `trigger` to insert into another remote table (account_journals table).

I recreated same trigger and adding another foreign table which refers to the account_journals table, but i still have same error.

How i created my foreigns tables :

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE accounts (
...
)
SERVER fdw_server
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'remote_accounts');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE account_journals (
...
)
SERVER fdw_server
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'remote_account_journals');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
```

The trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_account_journals AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON accounts FOR EACH row EXECUTE FUNCTION fill_account_journals();
```

`fill_account_journals()` function just insert record into `account_journals`.

When update record into accounts table :

```
new_database=# UPDATE accounts SET name = 'valou' WHERE id = 1;                                                                    
ERROR:  relation "remote_account_journals" does not exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.fill_remote_account_journals() line 8 at SQL statement
remote SQL command: UPDATE public.remote_accounts SET name = $2 WHERE ctid = $1 RETURNING id, name, ...
```

Any help is appreciated to solve my problem, thanks

Comment: 1) You need to add the trigger function as update to question. 2) What happens if you do a  stand alone `select * from account_journals` query?

Comment: I don't understand the end of your first question ?
For the second, i have all my finded records in remote table

Comment: You need to add the content of `public.fill_remote_account_journals()` to your question.